# IPython notebook keyboard shortcuts not working in Chrome

Tags: 14.04, ipython

I'm running a local IPython notebook server. (IPython  version `1.2.1`).

Running the notebook under Chrome means the keyboard shortcuts don't work. (Chrome version `36.0.1985.125`)

Running under Firefox works (Firefox version `31.0`).

Is there any way I can get IPython notebook keyboard shortcuts working in Chrome / Ubuntu?